# Beeper beeps if transmitter is turned of even if it shouldn't

Tags: betaflight, troubleshooting, flight-controller

I have turned off all beeper sound signals in Betaflight Configurator, but the beeper still beeps if the transmitter is turned off. I thought that that shouldn't happen when RX_LOST was turned off or not paired, but maybe I have understood it wrong? Or is a bug or a problem with my setup in some way?

Here is my diff all:

```
# 

# diff all

# version
# Betaflight / STM32F405 (S405) 4.1.5 Mar 16 2020 / 05:19:58 (d4e74e39c) MSP API: 1.42
# manufacturer_id: AIRB   board_name: OMNIBUSF4SD   custom defaults: YES

# start the command batch
batch start

# reset configuration to default settings
defaults nosave

board_name OMNIBUSF4SD
manufacturer_id AIRB
mcu_id 003c00403436511339373635
signature 

# resources
resource SERIAL_TX 1 NONE
resource SERIAL_TX 11 A09

# feature
feature SOFTSERIAL
feature TELEMETRY

# beeper
beeper -GYRO_CALIBRATED
beeper -RX_LOST
beeper -RX_LOST_LANDING
beeper -DISARMING
beeper -ARMING
beeper -ARMING_GPS_FIX
beeper -BAT_CRIT_LOW
beeper -BAT_LOW
beeper -GPS_STATUS
beeper -ACC_CALIBRATION
beeper -ACC_CALIBRATION_FAIL
beeper -READY_BEEP
beeper -DISARM_REPEAT
beeper -ARMED
beeper -SYSTEM_INIT
beeper -ON_USB
beeper -BLACKBOX_ERASE
beeper -CRASH_FLIP
beeper -CAM_CONNECTION_OPEN
beeper -CAM_CONNECTION_CLOSE
beeper -RC_SMOOTHING_INIT_FAIL

# map
map TAER1234

# serial
serial 0 64 115200 57600 0 115200
serial 2 2048 115200 57600 0 115200
serial 5 16384 115200 57600 0 115200
serial 30 32 115200 57600 0 115200

# aux
aux 0 0 0 1700 2100 0 0
aux 1 1 3 1300 1700 0 0
aux 2 13 2 1300 1700 0 0
aux 3 35 2 1700 2100 0 0
aux 4 36 1 1700 2100 0 0
aux 5 39 3 900 1300 0 0

# rxrange
rxrange 0 987 2011
rxrange 1 987 2011
rxrange 2 987 2011
rxrange 3 987 2011

# vtxtable
vtxtable bands 6
vtxtable channels 8
vtxtable band 1 BOSCAM_A A FACTORY 5865 5845 5825 5805 5785 5765 5745    0
vtxtable band 2 BOSCAM_B B FACTORY 5733 5752 5771 5790 5809 5828 5847 5866
vtxtable band 3 UNKNOWN  U FACTORY    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
vtxtable band 4 FATSHARK F FACTORY 5740 5760 5780 5800 5820 5840 5860    0
vtxtable band 5 RACEBAND R FACTORY    0    0 5732 5769 5806 5843    0    0
vtxtable band 6 IMD6     I CUSTOM  5732 5765 5828 5840 5866 5740    0    0
vtxtable powerlevels 2
vtxtable powervalues 0 1
vtxtable powerlabels 25 200

# master
set gyro_sync_denom = 2
set dyn_notch_range = LOW
set dyn_notch_width_percent = 0
set dyn_notch_q = 200
set dyn_notch_min_hz = 90
set acc_trim_pitch = 4
set acc_trim_roll = -6
set acc_calibration = 40,-16,-19
set min_check = 1010
set max_check = 1990
set rssi_channel = 9
set serialrx_provider = SBUS
set dshot_bidir = ON
set motor_pwm_protocol = DSHOT300
set vbat_scale = 108
set small_angle = 180
set pid_process_denom = 1
set osd_rssi_pos = 2426
set osd_rssi_dbm_pos = 120
set osd_tim_2_pos = 2455
set osd_flymode_pos = 2401
set osd_current_pos = 2440
set osd_mah_drawn_pos = 2448
set osd_warnings_pos = 14602
set osd_avg_cell_voltage_pos = 2433
set osd_flip_arrow_pos = 2095
set osd_stat_max_spd = OFF
set osd_stat_battery = ON
set vtx_band = 1
set vtx_channel = 1
set vtx_power = 2
set vtx_freq = 5865
set vcd_video_system = NTSC
set gyro_1_align_yaw = 2700
set gyro_rpm_notch_harmonics = 1

profile 0

profile 1

profile 2

# restore original profile selection
profile 0

rateprofile 0

# rateprofile 0
set roll_rc_rate = 90
set pitch_rc_rate = 90
set yaw_rc_rate = 90
set roll_expo = 35
set pitch_expo = 35
set yaw_expo = 35
set roll_srate = 80
set pitch_srate = 80
set yaw_srate = 80

rateprofile 1

rateprofile 2

rateprofile 3

rateprofile 4

rateprofile 5

# restore original rateprofile selection
rateprofile 0

# save configuration
save
#
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem: RX_LOST was disabled, but RX_AUX wasn't. I have the beeper set to beep if i center a swich, and since that is the default in Betaflight, the beeper turn on because it thought the switch was in that position.

I opened an issue about it here:
https://github.com/betaflight/betaflight/issues/9717

Comment: Actually, I think it is working as intended. A channel without input defaults to the center.
You can set a default value for the channel in betaflight, away from the center (1500). So it will not beep on RX loss.

Answer (score 4):

After making sure that you have the RX_Loss beeper disabled, the next port of call would be to check your DShot config.

It may not be the beeper that is making the noise - there is a DShot beacon configuration that allows you to set your ESCs to beep in the case of RX_Loss  - Id recommend you make sure you have that setting correct.

Edit: from your Diff All, it seems that beeper on RX_Loss May still be turned on, though I’m not sure.

Comment: I found the problem: RX_LOST was disabled, but RX_AUX wasn't. I have the beeper set to beep if i center a swich, and since that is the default in Betaflight, the beeper turn on because it thought the switch was in that position.

Comment: @HannesHultergård ah okay, glad you got it fixed

Answer (score 0):

Just turn off RX_Set (strange defined term)

Comment: Perhaps you could expand your answer to explain *why* you think this would solve the problem?